# Connecting to AxonServer node [192.168.99.100:8124] failed: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug

Tags: java, spring, axon

I use the axon server as a remote server in spring boot. not in the localhost. but when the spring boot application connects to the server it fails and show the following error.

```
Connecting to AxonServer node [192.168.99.100:8124] failed: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!
Failed to get connection to AxonServer. Scheduling a reconnect in 2000ms
[Channel<29>: (192.168.99.100:8124)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.netty.Utils$ByteBufAllocatorPreferDirectHolder
    at io.grpc.netty.Utils.getByteBufAllocator(Utils.java:140) ~[grpc-netty-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.start(NettyClientTransport.java:245) ~[grpc-netty-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:33) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:33) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:258) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:65) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:200) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95) ~[grpc-api-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127) ~[grpc-api-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1815) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**application.yml**

```
axon:
  axonserver:
    servers: 192.168.99.100:8124
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your Spring Boot app misses some dependencies. Perhaps you could include the  Axon Framework BOM or use the [Axon Initializr](https://start.axoniq.io)? That should make sure you have everything configured as needed.